# How can I get those URLs inside one Observable and how to subscribe them in my component?

Tags: angular

I have two URLs like this:

```javascript
private URL="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/?category=3"
private me="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/?category=2"
```

Currently I'm able to get one of them.

service:

```javascript
private URL="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/?category=3"
private me="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/?category=2"
getApi():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get (this.URL) 
}
```

component:

```javascript
ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getApi()  
    .subscribe(    
        data  => this.todo=data
);}
```

How can I get those URLs inside one `Observable` and how to `subscribe` them in my `component`?

Comment: with one call, you wanna make 2 HTTP calls? and return the 2 responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` when it comes to having a group of `observables`, and you care about the final emitted value of each.

Service:

```js
private URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/?category=3"
private me = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/?category=2"

getApi(): Observable<any> {
   return forkJoin({
      data1: this.http.get(this.URL),
      data2: this.http.get(this.me)
   })
}
```

Component:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.api.getApi().subscribe(({ data1, data2 }) => {
    console.log('response 1', data1);
    console.log('response 2', data2);
  })
}
```